# RedHat instance Python installation

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-ec2, redhat

When I try to install Python 2.7.8 in RedHat EC2 instance it is saying that "No package python27 available". What does it mean? Does RedHat 7.4 has no Python27 collection in its software bundle? My current verion is Python 2.7.5.

Comment: In most Linux distributions, Python 2.7 is part of a package simply called `python`

Answer (score 1):

```
yum search python2
```

it's called python2 not python27

It is usually installed by default

Answer (score 0):

try to install it using an external package :

```
rpm -Uvh https://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/python27/python27-python-2.7.8-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```